# Upgrading Windows 7 on a new Netbook - Problems

Tags: windows-7

I know this seems like a repeat of a question but i didn't get a clear answer from reading the other questions so im going to ask mine and hope i hear back good news.

I bought an Acer Aspire one netbook with windows 7 starter.  I have a DVD of Windows 7 Professional(x86) from MSNDAA through my college but when i tried to install it, i was given an error saying that i could only upgrade through the "Windows Anytime Upgrade"  Though, it only gives me the options of paying for an upgrade, which im not willing to do, or putting in an upgrade key.  I have a legitimate product key for windows 7 but it does not work for upgrading and the DVD does not allow for it.

Am i doing something wrong? is there another option? can i convert my product key to an upgrade key ? Im up for any option, windows 7 starter is pretty limited in its features...

Comment: When you tried to install, did you do it while in Windows, or did you boot from the disc?

Answer (score 1):

The current answers just state to do a full install - which is correct - but they don't say *why*, so thought I'd elaborate.

The Microsoft determined [Windows 7 Upgrade Paths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772579(WS.10).aspx) indicate that Starter can only do a "Repair-In-Place Upgrade to Windows 7" to Starter, no other version. It can do an Anytime-Upgrade to any of Home Premium, Professional or Ultimate.
(In otherwords you can't because Microsoft has intentionally designed it that way)

As an aside, the OP got thier copy free from a educational institution (via MSNDAA) - meaning that it possibly also has a different (and maybe incompatibile) software license when compared to the OEM install.

Answer (score 0):

If you completely delete your existing copy of Windows, the Pro version should not be able to try to 'upgrade' it. This seems a little drastic, but should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a custom install and do a completely new installation you should be able to do it.

Apparently it isn't not going to let you do an upgrade.

I have an Acer Netbook that I loaded with Windows 7 Home Premium upgrading from XP.  I had no choice but to do a full install.

Have you tried actually booting from the install disk?  Not, running the install after loading the Start OS?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is choose [`Windows Anytime Upgrade`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-anytime-upgrade), a special feature of Windows that allows you to upgrade editions in to time at all - however, it requires a special key and is mainly reserved / used just for people who bought retail packages.

What you need to do, as you are using starter edition is to simply put in your disk (or make a bootable USB stick) and perform a fresh install.